# Data from right table does not show using Left Join in Dev Studio

Tags: endeca

Im using Endeca Dev studio to perform a left join.  I have record adapters Items and ItemDetail with unique key itmno which im using for a Left join. Followed all the doc steps.
1) Create both record adapters
2) Create Cache for ItemDetail and add itmno in index
3) Create record assembler, specify itmno as key for Items and ItemDetailCache in Left Join setting.

I dont get any errors but data from ItemDetail doesnt show up in the jsp app. Im new to this so any guidance will really help.

Thanks

Comment: You should show your effort. Where is your code!!!

Answer (score 0):

A debugging tip - either add an output record adapter after each step or run forge with the --printRecords [number] flag.  These are both techniques to capture the state of the records for debugging and review.  This should help you see why the join isn't happening.